# Need ideas for running srm on large amount of files

Tags: linux, bash, unix, centos, rm

For security, I need to use srm (secure delete) rather than rm to delete some files: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srm_%28Unix%29

I currently have srm set up to run 3 passes over any data that I need to delete. The problem I'm having is that srm is running extremely extremely slowly on large amounts of files. For example, there is a 150 directory I tried to delete, and I found it to only have deleted 10GB over 1 week.

I know that srm will run slowly with multiple small files, but does directory depth matter as well? For most of the data I need to delete on a weekly basis, the actual files themselves are nested in various deep subdirectories. Would it help out if I flattened the directory structure before running srm?

Here are two workarounds I am looking at (maybe a combination of both), though I don't know how much they would help out:

1. Flatten all the directories structures before running srm. That way, all the files that need to be wiped out are in the same target dierctory.
2. Archive the entire directory before running srm. That way, the target file would be one big tar.gz file. Zipping up the data will likely take a while, but not as long as the srm would have taken.

Does anybody have any other suggestions on what I could do? Some others have used shred as well, but the results were similar and we ended up switching over to srm.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what "srm" is.

Comment: It looks like srm is some kind of secure file removal tool. Would the `shred` command from GNU Coreutils suit your needs?

Comment: Presumably http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srm_%28Unix%29

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't realize that others would be as unfamiliar with srm as myself. Duck posted the wiki for secure remove. I edited my post as well.

Comment: wouldn't a test of 1 GB of 1 file, vs 1 GB of data spread over 100 files in 100 subdirs give you a close enough approx? My (semi-educated) guess is that `srm` is overwriting the disk numerous times. That will be slow. Maybe there is an option to control how much it does? `srm -?`. Good lukc.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know much about srm, but might be worth trying :

```
find $mydir -type f -exec srm {} \;
find $mydir -type d -exec srm {} \;
```